# How to parse datetime between logs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to build a program that parse the logs and gives a date
The log only has hours, no dates, So what am I supposed to do?
I tried using datetime but it just enters the today date

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys
import logging
import datetime


def main():
    file = open("Desktop/a1.log", "r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    today = datetime.date.today()

    for line in lines:
        print (today, line)

main()
```

The logs are like this:

```
10:47:01> Screen 1: 2560x1080 at (0,1080) work area 2327x1080 at (233,1080)
10:47:01> Screen 2: 2560x1080 at (0,0) work area 2304x1080 at (256,0) primary
10:47:01> Screen 3: 1440x2560 at (-1440,0) work area 1440x2560 at (-1440,0)
```

and I need to set a first date and last date. How can I do this?

Comment: If the log doesn't have a date in it, how do you expect to get the proper date?

Comment: Thats what I need to do, I need to put a proper date

Comment: Do you want to use the `today` date and set the time from the log?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `today = datetime.date.today()` it is only grabbing the current time.
Instead you should use `today = datetime.datetime.now()`

Then you can use today.year, today.month, today.day, today.hour, today.minute, today.second to get the individual fields you want or `today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")` to get several values at once.

```
def main():
file = open("Desktop/a1.log", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
today = datetime.datetime.now()

for line in lines:
    print (today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), line)
```

More details can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/datetime.html

Comment: Like, I need to set an date and from that date I need the program to parse the hours to the other day, like if its 01 am it goes to another date, how do I do it?